# max and nested sql queries

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below table. With type version and name as columns

```
Type  version Name
Number  1     Name1
Number  2     Name2
Number  2     Name3
Char    1     Char1
```

I need output like max version of each type and their type and names. Like max version in number type is 2 and where as Char is 1.
Expected output

```
Type   Version Name
Number  2      Name2
Number  2      Name3
Char    1      Char1
```

I think i should max(version) to get the maximum version and how do i filter them using the Type? Please help me a write a SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select Type  ,version, Name
from  (select t.*,rank() over (partition by type order by version desc) as rnk
       from mytable t
       ) t
where  rnk=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use analytic functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, rank() over (partition by type order by version desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```